# jquery !$ bad code? or no?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was debugging a jquery code and i found the syntax !$, for me $ is very normal but i never saw !$, do you know guys what that means? or that is wrong or means something?

jquery file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!$(".class").length){
                alert();            
    }   
    if(google < 4 && !$(".class").hasClass("blue")) {
    $("#id").addClass('yellow');
</script>
```

Comment: `$(".class").length` will return you integer so i.e. `!0`

Comment: its just inversion of returned boolean value (it will be converted to boolean before inverted)

Comment: `$` is a function name. `$()` function call. It will return something. So `!` will invert that returned value.

Answer (score 2):

this one:

```
!$(".class").length
```

if there is no element with the classname `class` then length of it will be `0` which is equivalent to `false` in js and `!` denotes the not operation.

so, `!0` means `true`.

and this one:

```
!$(".class").hasClass("blue")
```

In jQuery `hasClass` returns boolean `true/false` so the output of it will be opposite.

if element hasclass blue then `!true` means `false` and if element does not hasclass then `!false` means `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting it as `!$` but the `!` is reading the full expression which is everything that follows not just `$`.

It might be clearer looking at is as:

```
if( !($(".class").length) ) //inner () gets evaluated then inverted by `!`
```

Or:

```
var hasClassLength = $(".class").length;
if(!hasClassLength)
```

These 2 examples are equivalent to what you have with `if( !$(".class").length )`

See [MDN Docs - logical not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT)

Answer (score 0):

`!` in this context means `NOT` in many programming languages and will simply modify that which follows.  It's often avoided where possible for exactly the same reason you're running into.  It can sometimes be awkward to scan through as it requires extra brain `processing` to parse in your head.

But sometimes it's essential and you'll see it used.

So as some have explained it's not referencing the $ itself, but what the $(".class").length resolves to.

You can keep typing `!` to continue adding NOTs.

**I've found it helpful to replace !'s with 'NOT' in my head when reading.**

So !$(".class").length in my head reads as: `The DOM element with .class does NOT have any length.`

An example:

```
true == true
!true == false
!false == true
!!true == true
```